# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20161107-1492-fykpuh.rb extconf.rb
--use-system-libraries
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
make: execvp: gcc: Bad file number
make: *** [generator.o] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3
for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out


An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Windows always has to install dev kit. But I prefer  windows rails installer https://s3.amazonaws.com/railsinstaller/Windows/railsinstaller-3.2.0.exe simple to install all dependencies. http://railsinstaller.org/en